# Formula of n-vector from latitude and longitude with three.js objects

Tags: three.js, latitude-longitude

I want the formula giving the n-vector (perpendicular to the globe) from latitude and longitude in a three.js scene. 
My code is currently the following, based on a list of cities (in the table called "wup"):

```
var conegeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 10, 10, 500, false);
var earthRadius = 6371;  // kilometres
var réduc = 0.02;
for (var iter=1;iter<1693;iter++){
    var cone = new THREE.Mesh(conegeometry, conematerial);
    var lat = wup[iter].Latitude*Math.PI/180;
    var lon = wup[iter].Longitude*Math.PI/180;
    cone.position.set (
        earthRadius * réduc * Math.cos(lat) * Math.cos(lon),
        earthRadius * réduc * Math.cos(lat) * Math.sin(lon),
        earthRadius * réduc * Math.sin(lat));
    cone.rotation.set (
        Math.sin(lat),
        Math.cos(lat) * Math.sin(lon),
        -Math.cos(lat) * Math.cos(lon));

    scene.add(cone);
}
```

Formulae come from [this article, p 402](http://www.navlab.net/Publications/A_Nonsingular_Horizontal_Position_Representation.pdf).

My aim is to have all cities represented as cones with the top at lat/lon position and the rest below the surface of earth, and perpendicularly to the earth surface (simplified as a sphere).
Latitude and longitude come from UN cities dataset, seem very clean and classical in degrees.

```
Santiago Del Estero -27,79511   -64,26149
Yerevan              40,181998  44,514619
Adelaide            -34,92866   138,59863
```

But something is wrong in the rotation formulae, and I can't find the right adjustment. Any idea?

Comment: I tried an instruction found [here](http://www.smartjava.org/content/render-open-data-3d-world-globe-threejs),  `cone.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0) );' which should mean the centre of the globe, but it does not work, cones don't look in the right direction, they show their side to the centre of the globe :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, much simpler than my initial idea. Based on [this project](http://www.smartjava.org/content/render-open-data-3d-world-globe-threejs) and this example at using the instruction `lookAt` which avoids complicate trigonometric formulae.

I also found that my formulae for lat/lon to x, y, z where wrong, and not corresponding to the formulae used in the project [shp.js](http://www.bram.us/2012/07/30/shp-js-javascript-shapefile-parser/) which I also use.

Objects can be set at facing a given point, here the centre of the earth. But then cones are cylinders and must for a reason I do not fully understand be turned of PI/2. So this worked:

```
     var lat =   wup[iter].Latitude*Math.PI/180;
     var lon = - wup[iter].Longitude*Math.PI/180;

     cone.position.set (
            Math.cos(lon) * 90 * Math.cos(lat),
            Math.sin(lat) * 90,
            Math.sin(lon) * 90 * Math.cos(lat)
            );
     cone.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0) ); //orientate the cone to the center of earth
     cone.translateZ( - earthRadius * réduc); //to follow the genral contraction
     cone.translateZ( coneHeight/2); //to put the top edge at lat/lon position
     cone.rotateX(- Math.PI / 2 ); //because cylinders.cones are drawn horizontally
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix two things: calculation of position and calculation of rotation.

**Position:**
The geographical coordinate system is left-handed (longitude grows towards east). Three.js uses a right-handed coordinate system (longitude grows towards west). Therefore the longitude value needs to be inverted in your geometry. Also, the formulae you found work for coordinates with Z-axis pointing up. Three.js has the Y-axis pointing up. So you need to swap the z and y formulas. This is the correct code for position:

```
    var lat = wup[iter].Latitude*Math.PI/180;
    var lon = - wup[iter].Longitude*Math.PI/180;

    cone.position.set (
        earthRadius * réduc * Math.cos(lat) * Math.cos(lon),
        earthRadius * réduc * Math.sin(lat),
        earthRadius * réduc * Math.cos(lat) * Math.sin(lon));
```

**Rotation:**
You just need to rotate the cone by their longitude/latitude values (not sines and cosines)

```
    cone.rotation.set ( 0, -lon, - Math.PI / 2 + lat);
```